# Function that accepts a generic Type or an array of the same Type

Tags: typescript, types

```js
  public treatment<Type>(input: Type | Type[]): Type {
    if (isArray(input)) {
      // input here is 100% Type[]
      return input.map((element) => treatment(element) /* <- this is telling Type 'Type[]' is not assignable to type 'Type'*/);
    }
    // input here is 100% Type
  }
```

The problem I'm facing is that IDE is complaining about the recursive call `treatment(element)`
while I thought it should not. As in the other hand hovering on the variable inside the `isArray` check or after, gives the correct typing.

Comment: What is `isArray`? What is `treatment`?

Comment: `isArray` is lodash function that ensures the `input` is an actual array, same as native `Array.isArray` .
and `treatment` is the only function (recursive call)

Comment: You annotated the return type of the function to be `Type`, yet you are returning an array with `input.map`.

Comment: hum this is the reason, true; the idea is to always return plain objects after `treatment` so I need to find a way to tell TS about that.
the thing about the recursive nature is the trick here.

Comment: Just pull the not-array path out into a different function and have treatment dispatch

Comment: So, as far as I can see, the idea is, if the input is an array, apply the `treatment` function to each item of the array; or, if the input is not an array, apply the function to the input itself; right? If so, this is a recursion, there has to be some condition, which would mean _not_ to applying the function. What is this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you want to approach that either a single value or each value of an array should be treated, you can solve it like this:

```
function treatEach<T, R>(input: T | T[], singleTreatment: (input: T) => R): R | R[] {
  if (input instanceof Array) {
    return input.map(singleTreatment);
  }
  let result: R = singleTreatment(input);
  return result;
}
```

input has got type `T` or `T[]` array. The function `singleTreatment` executes the treatment on an either *the* item or each item of the array.

The function either returns a treated item of type `R` or an array of treated items of type `R[]`.

Sample call:

```
let result: string[] | string = treatEach([1, 2, 3], i => i + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an appropriate [type guard](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard). For example, I changed a bit of your function typings:

```
function treatment<Type>(input: Type | Array<Type>): Type {
  if (input instanceof Array) {
    return /* some code using treatment recursive call which returns Type */
  }
  /** or smth else is going here */
  return input;
}
```

For example:

```
function treatment<Type>(input: Type | Array<Type>): Type {
  if (input instanceof Array) {
    return input.map(d => treatment(input))[0]; 
  }
  input['_meta'] = '_special_object_'
  return input;
}
```

Comment: try putting `return input.map((element) => treatment(element));` inside `if (input instanceof Array) {`
you just changed `isArray` of lodash which does the same guard.

Comment: If you want to return an array, then you shoud change returning type to `Type | Type[]` which will not work, because map function will change its returning type to `(Type | Type[])[]`

Comment: well I want to either return `Type | Array<Type>`.
`Like Type -> Type` and `Array<Type> -> TArray<Type>`

Comment: yes exactly, but there should be a way !

Comment: It's not possible, because every time you change your return type to `Whatever`, map function will return `Whatever[]`.

Comment: this is a recursive function ! I should declare two signatures ! to bind the input and output types.

Comment: You can use recursion, but you should return a correct type. What exactly you want this function for?

Comment: You can return `any` type for that specific reason as type can't be evaluated statically

Answer (score 0):

```
  treatment<T>(input: T): T;
  treatment<T>(input: T[]): T[];

  public treatment(input: unknown): unknown {
   if (input instanceof Array) {
    return input.map(d => treatment(input)); 
   }
   return treatment;
  }
```

This is the answer. I ended up overloading the function, so that TS can bind the input type with the output type, either one object or an array.

Note: You cannot apply this on a static method though !

next is to specify a type for T

Source:
https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-function-overloading/

Comment: `unknown` solving case, overloading is not necessary?

Comment: I guess you are right, this doesn't really solve anything. I'm deleting;

Comment: did you even try your solution? I think it contains errors. for example `return treatment;` looks strange. You return a function?